# How to send a code to the email written in a html input box

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bcrypt

I'm new with Angular and I'm trying to make a page in my website where I need to send a hash code to the e-mail written in an input box.

This is not a login ou sign-in page so I don't really need to save info in a database.

My idea is just to use bcrypt to create a hashcode and associate it with a x e-mail address, send a 'password' to that e-mail and then the person writes it in an empty input box and the bcrypt compares them.

I already have this:

```
<input id="address" type="email"  placeholder="Your e-mail" required/>
```

```
export class xclass implements OnInit {

    email = document.getElementById('address');

    async sendEmailVerification(){
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.email,10);
        const result = await bcrypt.compare(this.email, hash);
    
        if (result) //authentication failed or succeeded 
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

with  `.getElementById('address')` the variable 'email' is undefined.

Thank you.

Comment: Heads up, you're going to need a mail exchange server to facilitate the actual email portion of this. Generally speaking that requires authenticating with the MX server with credentials, so you don't want this functionality on the front end in the first place.

Comment: but its just a simple thing, you sure i need a server for that? am I too far away with bcrypt?

Comment: If you generate the hash locally. Why not just display it in the page then?

Comment: @imma what purpose is bcrypt serving here? Do you need a server to send the emails? Well, if the app you are creating only ever runs on your machine and never gets exposed to the public Internet, then sure, you don't need a server. Otherwise you will be exposing your Mail Exchange credentials to the world because **html/javascript are front-end technologies**